retrieve value from month furthest back in same FY
I have a dataset where rows correspond to data collected at different points in time like so:



metric
date
FY
result




visits
03/01/2024
FY24
17


visits
04/01/2024
FY24
21


visits
05/01/2024
FY24
34


visits
06/01/2024
FY25
99


visits
07/01/2024
FY25
11


visits
08/01/2024
FY25
27



I want to add a column that shows the value from the result column that (a) is in the same FY as the current month AND (b) is furthest back
-every metric in the dataset set does not have values 12 months back, some may have 3 or 7 months or 11 months, etc....
desired output:



metric
date
FY
result
year_ago




visits
03/01/2024
FY24
17
17


visits
04/01/2024
FY24
21
17


visits
05/01/2024
FY24
34
17


visits
06/01/2024
FY25
99
99


visits
07/01/2024
FY25
11
99


visits
08/01/2024
FY25
27
99



I am trying to use LAG in a case statement to loop through the previous 12 months but it returns 0 instead, not sure if multiple expressions are matching or mismatching strings and integers?
CASE 
    WHEN result <> 0 AND LAG(FY,1) = FY THEN COALESCE(LAG(result,1) OVER (PARTITION BY date ORDER BY date),0)
    WHEN result <> 0 AND LAG(FY,2) = FY THEN COALESCE(LAG(result,2) OVER (PARTITION BY date ORDER BY date),0)
    WHEN result <> 0 AND LAG(FY,3) = FY THEN COALESCE(LAG(result,3) OVER (PARTITION BY date ORDER BY date),0)
    WHEN result <> 0 AND LAG(FY,4) = FY THEN COALESCE(LAG(result,4) OVER (PARTITION BY date ORDER BY date),0)
    WHEN result <> 0 AND LAG(FY,5) = FY THEN COALESCE(LAG(result,5) OVER (PARTITION BY date ORDER BY date),0)
    WHEN result <> 0 AND LAG(FY,6) = FY THEN COALESCE(LAG(result,6) OVER (PARTITION BY date ORDER BY date),0)
    WHEN result <> 0 AND LAG(FY,7) = FY THEN COALESCE(LAG(result,7) OVER (PARTITION BY date ORDER BY date),0)
    WHEN result <> 0 AND LAG(FY,8) = FY THEN COALESCE(LAG(result,8) OVER (PARTITION BY date ORDER BY date),0)
    WHEN result <> 0 AND LAG(FY,9) = FY THEN COALESCE(LAG(result,9) OVER (PARTITION BY date ORDER BY date),0)
    WHEN result <> 0 AND LAG(FY,10) = FY THEN COALESCE(LAG(result,10) OVER (PARTITION BY date ORDER BY date),0)
    WHEN result <> 0 AND LAG(FY,11) = FY THEN COALESCE(LAG(result,11) OVER (PARTITION BY date ORDER BY date),0)
ELSE 0
END AS year_ago


How do your financial years work? in your sample data you have date: 8/1/2022 and FY24, how is this possible?

haha sorry, my mistake in the example

Your requirement is easy to come by using window functions along with conditional aggregation:
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT t.*, MIN(date) OVER (PARTITION BY FY) AS min_date
    FROM yourTable t
)

SELECT metric, date, FY, result,
       MAX(CASE WHEN date = min_date THEN result END) OVER (PARTITION BY FY) year_ago
FROM cte
ORDER BY FY, date;


Here is one way:
select 
     metric
   , dte
   , FY
   , result
   , (  select min(result)
        from MyTbl b
        where a.metric=b.metric
        and a.FY=b.FY
        and dte=(select min(dte)
                from MyTbl c
                where c.metric=b.metric
                and c.FY=b.FY
                )
    ) as EarliestResultInFY
from MyTbl a

For each row in your table (a), we find all rows for the same [metric, FY] (alias b), and limit them to the earliest date for the same [metric, FY] (alias c).
The second min (in alias 'b') is used to guarantee a single row (for each a), just in case you have multiple rows for the same [metric, date, FY].
